# Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in home/invadmin1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/.../automapper.php on line 37

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website where I got this warning on my admin page, how can i fix this or remove it from the page.

[image]

here is code I found on mentioned file on line 37

```
is_admin() && ( strpos( vc_request_param( 'action' ), 'vc_automapper' ) !== false || 'vc-automapper' === vc_get_param( 'page' ) ) && add_action( 'admin_init', 'vc_automapper_init' );
```

how can I warning or remove those warning from website.

Comment: You would have to check that `vc_request_param( 'action' )` did not return null, resp. provide str_pos with an alternative value, such as an empty string - `vc_request_param( 'action' ) ?? ''`. _BUT_, you should rather not modify the coding of 3rd-party plugins to begin with - you will lose your changes on the next plugin update. You should check if there is an update available, and if not, ask the plugin author to provide one that fixes the issue.

Comment: I think this may be a bug with the WPBakery plugin.  It's not anticipating no action in the HTTP request.  If you give it one, e.g. by adding "?action=foo" to the end of your URL, the error seems to go away.